# Is it possible to share the same "hard drive" partition with a dual-boot?

Tags: filesystems, multi-boot, file-transfer, file-permissions

I want to dual-boot my PC with Linux and Windows. Is it possible to save a file on my Windows partition and when I load the Linux partition, be able to see that saved file on Windows and visa versa?

Example:
While in Windows, I download a file called `foo.txt` in `C:\foo.txt`.
I switch over to Linux. Would I be able to see that text file and edit it?

I'm using `Windows 7` and `Ubuntu`. I think it's a `FAT32` hard drive.

Comment: What version of Windows exactly are you using?  Is the data partition you want to share `FAT32` or `NTFS`?  If we are talking about `NTFS` you run the risk of files being corrupted since most versions of Linux( Ubuntu for example ) has unofficial `NTFS` drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound: have you ever experienced this potential problem? I've heard about it, but I did "Run Linux -> mount Windows/NTFS file system -> copy/modify files" on a dual-boot system for over a year without any issues.

Comment: Don't forget that Linux and Windows have different line-endings for text files. While many editors can automatically detect and handle this, Notepad (the Windows default) can not!

Comment: @Ash Same here.. I've been mounting NTFS partitions under Linux no problem. Well, almost - I find them much slower than native linux partitions, but I've never *detected* any data corruption.

Comment: @Ramhound @Ash @KevinM I'm using windows 7 and ubuntu. And I'm pretty sure it be `FAT32` drive.

Comment: @Ash - I only said its possible. I read that possability on the Ubuntu forum from what I assume to be a hardcore Ubuntu verteran.

Comment: @RobAveryIV - Verify what you are using exactly, of course no matter what you are using, Hennes answer applies to you.

Comment: @Ramhound: I may have read the same post then :). Since I haven't experienced it, always interested in "positive examples" of the problem. Also, is it still possible to install Win7 on FAT32?

Comment: For completeness sake: I have experienced NTFS corruption when writing to it from Linux. I booted Knoppix **5** (release date: Feb 2006). At the time it was known that NTFS **write** support was flaky. Since then NTFS support has improved significantly but I am still reluctant to use it. I guess the same prejudice holds for many other people.

Comment: @Hennes, thanks for the firsthand account. As I mentioned, no issues in recent times for me, but I was pretty gung-ho because I didn't know about any problems...

Comment: @Ash - **IF** its possible its limited to the 32-bit client. Windows XP can be upgraded to Windows Vista and Windows Vista can be upgraded to Windows 7. This means a 32-bit version of Windows XP installed on a FAT32 HDD could be upgraded to Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It can be done in several ways:

1. If the windows partition is FAT or FAT32 then you can just mount it.
   The syntax for that is `mount -t vfat /dev/sdax /mnt/My_windows_drive`.
   Replace the sdax with the correct partition and /mnt/My_windows_drive with a folder of your choosing.
2. If the windows partition is NTFS then you can do it the same way, but change `vfat` to `ntfs`.
   **WARNING**: Older versions were unreliable when writing to NTFS. I heard this got solved, but I am still not comfortable with writing to a NTFS formatted volume.
3. Or you can just create a third partition on the drive and share that. (E.g. c: for windows boot and programs, D:(FAT32) for shared data.  [E:] for Linux.
4. Finally, you can also do the reverse and mount the linux partitions from windows. See [the ext2 filesystem driver for windows](http://www.fs-driver.org/).